# Try to approximate this function at these three points for a deviation Δx =0.1

Tags: calculus, differential

Take the function y=x^2 . Take three points, say x=0, x=1, x=3. Try to approximate this function at these three points for a deviation Δx =0.1. For which of the three points the approximation works best? For which point it works worst? Can you explain why, in a qualitative way, just by looking at the graph of the function y=x2. Are my answers correct?

Here's what I have so far
dy=f'(x)dx

Find dy if y=x^2
dy=2x

Find dy when x=0, x=1, x=3 and dx=.01
dy = 2(0)(.01)=0
dy = 2(1)(.01)=.02
dy = 2(3)(.01)=.06

Comment: What approximations are allowed?  Without some restriction, you can approximate the function with $y=x^2$, which has zero error.  Are you supposed to use a linear function?

Comment: Problem doesn't say what approximations are allowed, but linear function y=2x-1

Comment: I used the linearization formula L(x) = f(a)+f'(a)(x-a) to get For x=0

L(x) = (0)^2+ 2(0)(.01) = 0

x=1

L(x) = (1)^2+2(1)(.01) = 1.02

x=3

L(x) = (3)^2+2(3)(.01) = 9.06 These estimates are pretty close to the real values of x^2

x=0 y=0

x=1 y=1

x=3 y=9

Answer (score 0):

Well, if we use Euler's Method as an approximation, then we can find approximations easily as follows:
$$f'(x) = 2x$$
Now, we apply this with a step size $\Delta x = 0.1$ to solve the problem. Notice that for this specific problem, we can simply write the approximation of $f(1)$ as a finite series:
$$f(1) \approx \sum_{k = 0}^{9} 0.2k,$$
and the series can be evaluated simply:
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{9} 0.2k = \frac{(0 + 1.8)(10)}{2} = \boxed{0.9}.$$

The approximation is low. This makes sense because the curve is always concave up. I leave you to evaluate the approximations of $f(2)$ and $f(3).$

Answer (score 0):

If you are required to use a linear function, you can use least squares techniques to find the best fit to your three points.  The fact that you are evaluating $\Delta x$ suggests that you should fit $x=\sqrt y$ instead of the other way around.  When I plug the data into Excel it finds $x=1.6888-0.2046y$ as the best linear approximation.  Now evaluate the error in $x$. I find they all exceed $0.1$